# How to create a function in optional parameter in Typescript

Tags: typescript, function

I wonderer how to have a function with parameter option.

I have a function who I have
label, brand, and shop parameter.
But it's not working and I don't know how to fix that..

```
const getTransaction = (shop?:string, brand?:string, label:string) => {
if(shop && brand === null){
   return label
}else {
  return shop + brand;
  }
}
getTransaction("brand","topshop", "topshop - brand")
getTransaction(null,null, "topshop - brand")
```

Comment: Install an IDE. `A required parameter cannot follow an optional parameter.` is what the error says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot put optional parameters before mandatory parameters

`(label:string, shop?:string, brand?:string)` should work